# Not able to load more than one jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

No matter what script I put first the second one always refuses to load,and I'm either stuck with the jQuery source code, or my function. In which I obviously  need both to perform the task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jbasics/basicJquery.css">
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <h1 id="header">List</h1>
            <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
            <ul>
                <li id="one"class="hot">fresh figs</li>
                <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
                <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
                <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"</script>
        <script src="../jbasics/basicJquery.js"</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code which you have written

Comment: You need to close script block like `<script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
        <script src= "../jbasics/basicJquery.js">  </script>`

Comment: `<script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"</script>
<script src="../jbasics/basicJquery.js"</script>
```

Is wrong, you are missing `>` at the end of your `script`. Here is the solution :

```
<script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jbasics/basicJquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: 
`<script src="../jbasics/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

The script block needs to be closed.